# jQuery Gantt not initialising

Tags: jquery, gantt-chart

I'm not too sure why my jQuery Gantt isn't working - I've followed the exact examples as seen on the website. This is my code so far:

```
$(function () {

    "use strict";

    $(".gantt").gantt({
        source: [{
            name: "Sprint 0",
            desc: "Analysis",
            values: [{
                from: "/Date(1320192000000)/",
                to: "/Date(1322401600000)/",
                label: "Requirement Gathering",
                customClass: "ganttRed"
            }]
        }, {
            name: " ",
            desc: "Scoping",
            values: [{
                from: "/Date(1322611200000)/",
                to: "/Date(1323302400000)/",
                label: "Scoping",
                customClass: "ganttRed"
            }]
        }, {
            name: "Sprint 1",
            desc: "Development",
            values: [{
                from: "/Date(1323802400000)/",
                to: "/Date(1325685200000)/",
                label: "Development",
                customClass: "ganttGreen"
            }]
        }, {
            name: " ",
            desc: "Showcasing",
            values: [{
                from: "/Date(1325685200000)/",
                to: "/Date(1325695200000)/",
                label: "Showcasing",
                customClass: "ganttBlue"
            }]
        }, {
            name: "Sprint 2",
            desc: "Development",
            values: [{
                from: "/Date(1326785200000)/",
                to: "/Date(1325785200000)/",
                label: "Development",
                customClass: "ganttGreen"
            }]
        }, {
            name: " ",
            desc: "Showcasing",
            values: [{
                from: "/Date(1328785200000)/",
                to: "/Date(1328905200000)/",
                label: "Showcasing",
                customClass: "ganttBlue"
            }]
        }, {
            name: "Release Stage",
            desc: "Training",
            values: [{
                from: "/Date(1330011200000)/",
                to: "/Date(1336611200000)/",
                label: "Training",
                customClass: "ganttOrange"
            }]
        }, {
            name: " ",
            desc: "Deployment",
            values: [{
                from: "/Date(1336611200000)/",
                to: "/Date(1338711200000)/",
                label: "Deployment",
                customClass: "ganttOrange"
            }]
        }, {
            name: " ",
            desc: "Warranty Period",
            values: [{
                from: "/Date(1336611200000)/",
                to: "/Date(1349711200000)/",
                label: "Warranty Period",
                customClass: "ganttOrange"
            }]
        }],
        navigate: "scroll",
        scale: "weeks",
        maxScale: "months",
        minScale: "days",
        itemsPerPage: 10,
        onItemClick: function (data) {
            alert("Item clicked - show some details");
        },
        onAddClick: function (dt, rowId) {
            alert("Empty space clicked - add an item!");
        },
        onRender: function () {
            if (window.console && typeof console.log === "function") {
                console.log("chart rendered");
            }
        }
    });

    $(".gantt").popover({
        selector: ".bar",
        title: "I'm a popover",
        content: "And I'm the content of said popover."
    });
});
```

I've included a link here to show it: http://jsfiddle.net/Zn2ML/

Not sure why it doesn't look like this: http://taitems.github.com/jQuery.Gantt/

Comment: You are probably missing the CSS files.
And you are missing :  `jquery.fn.gantt.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are missing to include javascript files and css files from:

http://taitems.github.com/jQuery.Gantt/

start from an easy example, do not forget to include all the css and javascript like in the example, and then start doing your code updates to make it fit your needs.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Zn2ML/2/ I've managed to work something out - but the icons seem to be missing... what's wrong :-S

Comment: You should download them and put them under a folder in your server and then in the css point to them , make sure what you are doing is legal.

Comment: http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/img/icon_sprite.png is included by http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/css/style.css but most browsers still fail at saving a complete webpage.

Answer (score 0):

See this example

the icons not be loaded for this...

you code

```
.fn-gantt .dataPanel {
    margin-left: 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
    background-image: url(../img/grid.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 24px 24px;
}
```

change for:

```
.fn-gantt .dataPanel {
    margin-left: 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
    background-image: url(http://taitems.github.com/jQuery.Gantt/img/grid.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 24px 24px;
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Zn2ML/3/)

Comment: But then if `taitems.github.com` goes down, he will loose the images, so best way is to download them and use them locally.

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly Obviously, the best solution is the you say, but i write the fast option... fix this solution is very easy :)